# Using layout_alignBaseline and layout_alignBottom in RelativeLayout together

Tags: android, layout, android-relativelayout

I'm trying to get a layout that looks something like this:

[image: Relative layout example]

That is:

1. `TextView` aligned (with margins) to parent left and top.
2. An `EditText` to the left of the `TextView`, to the right of the `Button` and baseline-aligned with the `TextView`.
3. A `Button` aligned (with only a right margin) to the parent right. And here's the broken part: bottom-aligned to the `EditText`.

For whatever reason it doesn't work. Here's the code I'd expect to work:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="32dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
        android:text="Text:" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edit"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/text"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/button"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/text"
        android:ems="10" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/edit"
        android:layout_marginRight="32dp"
        android:text="Ok" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

That comes out like this:

[image: Broken RelativeLayout]

What's going on?

## Edit

Sorry I'm not sure why I changed this example, but in my code I'm actually using an `ImageButton`, not `Button`, so the solution can't involve aligning with the baseline of the button - the `EditText` must be aligned with the *bottom* (or middle if that is possible) of the button.

Comment: there may be a margin coming from a theme ?

Answer (score 4):

Try this..

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="32dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
    android:text="Text:" />


<EditText
    android:id="@+id/edit"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/text"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/button"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/text"
    android:ems="10" >

    <requestFocus />
</EditText>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/edit"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/edit"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
    android:text="Ok" />
```

Comment: Actually that works but only because the button has a baseline, I used a bad example in my question (sorry!) - actually I am using an `ImageButton`, not a `Button`.

Comment: so what? it will work with ImageButton too.
alignBaseline+alignBottom will always be on the bottom of 1 line

Answer (score 1):

Appears to be a bug affecting alignBaseline being used as an anchor for other children. https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=73697&thanks=73697